# Spark & HCatalog?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, apache-spark, hcatalog

I feel comfortable with loading HCatalog using Pig and was wondering if it's possible to use Spark instead of Pig. Unfortunately, I'm quite new with Spark...
Can you provide any materials on how to start? Are there any Spark libraries to use?
Any Examples? I've made all exercises on [http://spark.apache.org/](http://spark.apache.org/docs) but they are focusing on RDD and don't go any further..

I will be grateful for any help...
Regards 
 
Pawel

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the following link       for using HCatalog InputFormat wrapper with Spark; which was written prior to SparkSQL.
https://gist.github.com/granturing/7201912

Answer (score 1):

You can use spark SQL to read from Hive Table instead of HCatalog.

https://spark.apache.org/sql/

You can apply same transformations like Pig using Spark Java/Scala/Python language like filter, join, group by..

Comment: You can go even further than just base transformations to data sets, you can also create hive tables directly in Spark/Load them etc directly through SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Our systems have loaded both and we can use either.  Spark takes on traits of the language you are using, Scala, Python...,. For example using Spark with Python you can utilize many of the libraries of Python within Spark.